# How to use callback on $.post to get returned data (async function problem)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, asynchronous, return

I'd like to get `true` or `false` from $.post by calling `abc()`. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) answer, but I don't get it to work.

Can someone give me a short example with my code?

```
function abc() {
    form = $('form');
    formData = form.serialize();

    $.post('file.php', formData, function(result) {
        form.each(function() {
            if (result === this.id) {
                return true;
                error = true;
            }
        });

        if (error === false) { // no error
            return true;
        }
    });
}

if (abc()) {
    // true // <- doesn't work, because $.post is an async function
}
```

Comment: You asked this earlier today and it got closed then too

Comment: Also  `error = true;` will never be set because it is after a (useless) return

Comment: You cannot call abc and test the result. Simply change your code so you move the code you had when true to a function you call when true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by returning `promise` value, Then check it by using `done` method.

```
function abc() {
   form = $('form');
   formData = form.serialize();

   return $.post('file.php', formData);
}

abc().done(function(result){
    if(result === 'abc')
    // do something.
});
```

You can also use `Callback` function like this

```
function abc(mycalback) {
    form = $('form');
    formData = form.serialize();

    $.post('file.php', formData, mycalback);
}

function mycalback(response) {
    var result = false;
    form.each(function() {
            if (response=== this.id) {
                return true;
                result = true;
            }
        });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @xif80599

Comment: Isn't it possible to return just true or false from abc()? I've updated my code btw. :).

Comment: From my point of view, you should control value from `promise` value instead

Comment: What about callbacks? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) is an example of a callback. Do you know how to use this in my case?

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please take a look @xif80599 . However, return boolean in your case does not make sense, So you need to do something as you wish instead of return true/false;

Answer (score 0):

Have in mind that the response of the call to `$.post` is only available when the promise fulfills.

So, in order for the response to be available, you have to wait for the promise (as you do in `abc` in order to know what to return).

Having that in mind, you have to return the promise in `abc` in order to wait for its resolution:

```
function abc() {
    form = $('form');
    formData = form.serialize();

    // Note here we return the promise
    return $.post('file.php', formData, function(result) {
        if (result === 'abc') {
             return true;
        } else {
             return false;
        }
    });
}

// Now we wait for the promise to be resolved
abc().then(function(result) {
    if (result) {
        // Do your thing here!
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem now is, that result is always "true" because it shows me the returned data from php and not just true or false :/.